# PHPmyadmin pop-up error notice keeps appearing when clicking on columns of databases

Tags: phpmyadmin, server

I keep receiving a pop-up error, when clicking on columns in databases:

> Some errors have been detected on the server, please look at the
>   bottom of this window.
>
> Notice in .\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php#55 Undefined
>   variable: server
>
> Backtrace
>
> .\libraries\structure.lib.php#2433:
>   include(.\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php)
>   .\tbl_structure.php#45: PMA_displayHtmlForColumnChange( string
>   'registration', string 'users', NULL, string 'tbl_structure.php', )

How to solve this matter?

Comment: Which phpMydmin version?

Comment: Latest version at the moment (4.3.10)

Answer (score 101):

Append the following line

```
 $cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

inside **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** file to disable this annoying window.

Comment: Thanks, it worked... I hate this annoyance, because the report shows only notices anyway, not the actual errors.

Comment: I started getting errors after an update to pma. Might have something to do with MariaDB incompatibility in updated versions mine is `Version: 4:3.4.11.1-2+deb7u1` This solution does effectively work around it.

Comment: I found this in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. It worked perfectly.

Comment: You need to add if not available line. For me it was not available.

Comment: I found it in  `/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin ` and it's work , thanks

Comment: Wait a minute; isn't this just window dressing?  Hiding the error never fixes the problem.   Unless you are saying the error isn't actually a problem which is a different thing.

Answer (score 28):

This error is caused by a line of code in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`.

It seems when I installed phpMyAdmin using `apt`, the version in the repository (phpMyAdmin v4.6.6) is not fully compatible with PHP 7.2. There is a newer version available on the official website (v4.8 as of writing), which fixes these compatibility issues with PHP 7.2.

You can [download the latest version](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) and install it manually or wait for the repositories to update with the newer version.

Alternatively, you can make a small change to `sql.lib.php` to fix the error.

Firstly, backup `sql.lib.php` before editing.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php.bak
```

Edit `sql.lib.php` using `vi`:

```
sudo vi /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Using `nano`:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (for nano) or `?` (for vi/vim) and search for:

```
(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

Replace it with:

```
((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

Save file and exit. (Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for `nano` users / hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> then type `:wq` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it! Only thing I'd like to add it that you can use more user friendly editor to edit that file, I used sublime: `sudo subl /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php`

Comment: I think that if you cannot update the version of phpmyadmin, then this is the best solution. Rather than disable error reporting, just fix the issue, cheers!

Comment: It is February 2020 now, almost two years after the original answer is posted, and `apt` is still distributing **phpMyAdmin** version **4.6.6**. I know open-source projects take a while, but come-on, this is important stuff!!!

Answer (score 20):

Just add this line in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

```
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

Answer (score 12):

if **exists** then update **other wise add** this line in  `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file

```
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Answer (score 6):

Strangely, none of the above solutions worked for me.

So I had to edit this file:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php
```

Which is getting included in every phpmyadmin script files.

And place this line at the very bottom:

```
 $cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

Answer (score 3):

for me it worked....

just add this line `$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';`
inside **C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php**
  **(FOR WINDOWS!!!!)**

and **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php** for other

Answer (score 2):

I just **solved** the same problem, every time I enter on my database tables that errors occurs. It seems that PhpMyadmin is not compatible with php version. I have php 7.3 upgrade from 7.0 and NOW **PhpMyadmin 4.8.5** from 4.6.

Comment: This is the most underrated solution in this thread. Updating my phpMyAdmin fixed all the errors I was getting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Its a php and phpMyAdmin compatibility issue.

> **Which PHP versions does phpMyAdmin support?**
> https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq1-31 Could be helpful.

Eitherway, you can turn off `Error Reporting` by adding the rule below to your `config.inc.php` and your errors will disappear.

```
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

If you are using `WampServer` on Windows, you can find the file here `C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.1.1\config.inc.php`.

> `C:\` is your disk where you have installed wampserver and
> `phpmyadmin5.1.1` is my version. This will be variable based on the phpMyAdmin version in your local server.

For those using `Xampp`, your file is here `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 0):

no need to do any thing in ubunto
just set SQL compatibility mode: =MYSQ40
while importing your tables.
it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

just add this line `$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never'; inside C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`
(FOR WINDOWS!!!!)
It's work for me